# Sql query from a variable How to apostrophe each value

Tags: php, mysql, moodle

I have an array of usernames from Moodle and i want to see the id's they correspond to. Because it is impratical to $array=('user1','user'2....), and the size/contents may vary, i've found a useful function around here that seems to do what i need:

```
function apply_quotes($item)
{
return "'".mysql_real_escape_string($item)."'";
}

$dataClip=array_map("apply_quotes",$dataClip);
$allUsers=array_map("apply_quotes",$allUsers);
```

Outputting $allUsers gives me this:

```
Array ( [0] => 'guest
' [1] => 'admin
' [2] => 'xpto.xy
' [3] => 'a.maia
' [4] => 'd.mano
' [5] => 'a.cabral
' [6] => 'd.mateus
' )

//$allUsers gets me all usernames of Moodle, $dataClip gets me all usernames from an url xml file. 
$results=array_intersect((array)$dataClip,(array)$allUsers);
```

Output of $results:

```
Array ( [0] => 'a.cabral
' [1] => 'a.maia
' [54] => 'd.mateus
' )

list($usernamewhere,$usernameparams)=$DB->get_in_or_equal($results,SQL_PARAMS_NAMED,'username');
             $sql="SELECT u.id AS userid,u.username
                   FROM {user} u
                   WHERE u.username {$usernamewhere}";
                   $users=$DB->get_records_sql($sql,$usernameparams);
                   foreach($users as $user){
                       echo $user->userid. ' - ' . $user->username.'<br/>';
                       }
```

EDIT:  And after the query, I get no output. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: A PHP syntax error or a MySQL syntax error? I also suggest you read it.

Comment: Remove `AS username` from where clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
  $sql="SELECT u.id AS userid
        FROM user u
        WHERE u.username  IN('".implode(',',$results)."')";
```

- you missed single quotes.
- dont give aliase name in where clause
- dont use {} in mysql

EDIT:

change this

```
  $userids = $DB->get_records_sql($sql);
  echo $userids;
```

to

```
  $userids = $DB->get_recordset_sql($sql);
  foreach ($userids as $ids) {

        $userid = $ids->userid;

        echo $userid;
    }
```

Comment: downvoter , can you explain why or you just downvote ? better do an explanation to make it better the answer.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with ur code let me up it, not sure why its downvoted.

Comment: @echo_ME moodle table syntax forces me to use {}. single quotes solves the error, but only prints Array  on screen. My variable $results is the outcome of an intersection between two arrays.

Comment: @echo_Me Doesn't print anything. And i'm certain i have users on my moodle database as well usernames on my $results.

Comment: see this what it gives `var_dump($userids);`

Comment: @echo_Me array(0){}. Makes no sense. Let me show what is before.

Comment: you sure this have right values . ` echo implode(',',$results) ;` try echo it before the query and give what it prints.

Comment: @echo_ME echo implode('<br/>',$results);  gets me, before the query,gives me the intersection between those 2 arrays. 3 usernames

a.cabral

a.maia

d.mateus

Comment: @echo_Me Nothing, as in blank page. Tried several stuff, get_in_or_equal($sql); get_record_list('user','username',$results,'id');  still nothing.

Comment: blank page? you  dont have error ini on ? use this in very top page and see what error it gives `ini_set('display_errors',1);`

Comment: @echo_Me i have it on, as well as Moodle's developer debug on. Just on this problem i'm having I get blank page.

Comment: just try this only to see if it works `WHERE u.username  IN('cabral','maia','mateus')";`

Comment: @echo_Me I see a.cabral id and a.maia id, as well,  9 and 10 respectively. d.mateus is not in here( he is in Moodle on my Win7, he is not on Moodle Unix). Now we are getting somewhere :) So..by typing directly the username, it works. Why is not working with the variable?

Comment: if it works like that it means your variable `implode(',',$results)` is not good. there is some error in it. can you post exactly what it gives this implode ?

Comment: @echo_Me edited my post. Totally confused with this one.

Comment: Please , i said give me what it gives this variable `echo implode(',',$results) ;` give exactly what it gives.

Comment: @echo_Me Edited again.

Comment: @user3178356 i think your values in the `$results` they should be quoted with single quotes . Like that `IN('cabral','maia','mateus')` and yours gives this `IN(cabral,maia,mateus)` wich is wrong. reproduce your variable with the single quotes.

Comment: @echo_Me so are you saying that after using the array_intersect to get the usernames, I should put apostrophes to each one of them, and only then will the query will work?

Comment: yes , exactly . make single quotes to usernames before building your array . and your query should work

Comment: @echo_Me Ok thank you for your patience. Wanted to upvote your answer, but lost a bunch of points, don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

{} is specific to Moodle, it replaces the table name with the full table name - database + prefix.

http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Data_manipulation_API#moodle_database::get_records_sql.28.29

$DB->get_records_sql() returns an array of objects

For the original question, you are getting a syntax error because the usernames are not enclosed in quotes.

The correct way to do this is

```
$usernames = array('username1', 'username2', ... );
list($usernamewhere, $usernameparams) = $DB->get_in_or_equal($usernames, SQL_PARAMS_NAMED, 'username');
$sql = "SELECT u.id AS userid, u.username
        FROM {user} u
        WHERE u.username {$usernamewhere}";
$users = $DB->get_records_sql($sql, $usernameparams);
foreach ($users as $user) {
    echo $user->userid . ' - ' . $user->username . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: Thank you Russell, i've updated my post with a new question regarding the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

The correct one is

```
$sql="SELECT u.id AS userid
FROM user u
WHERE u.username IN('".implode(',',$results)."')";
```

- you are using {} for the table name but its not a PHP variable

Comment: ha nice to have downvotes but have some guts to make a comment so that if have done some mistake I can correct myself.

Answer (score 0):

SQL doesn't accetps the syntax. Remove the AS in the WHERE part:

```
$sql="SELECT u.id AS userid
  FROM {user} u
  WHERE u.username IN(".implode(',',$results).")";
```

Comment: It is only printing the word Array on screen.My variable $results is the outcome of an intersection between two arrays

Comment: Probably you need to complete the code. If you are using _username_, and they are strings, your $sql have to be something like ... IN ('user1', 'user2').

Comment: The $results variable is an array of usernames that may vary according to current db situation, it can be small or huge, so i can't do IN('user1','user2'.....'user100000').